Missing bluetooth device with disk encryption
I'm struggling with the RTL8821A Bluetooth adapter which is embedded to RTL8821AE wlan. This is notable in both, encrypted ZFS, and LUKS over LVM cases.
What is weird that the device works fine with an unencrypted filesystem.
What I noticed, that a few related kernel modules in encrypted system are not loaded:
A list of modules with disk encryption
vilius@vilius-laptop:~$ lsmod | grep rtl
rtl8821ae             368640  0
btcoexist             290816  1 rtl8821ae
rtl_pci                40960  1 rtl8821ae
rtlwifi               143360  3 rtl_pci,rtl8821ae,btcoexist
mac80211             1769472  3 rtl_pci,rtl8821ae,rtlwifi
cfg80211             1372160  2 rtlwifi,mac80211

List of modules without encryption
vilius@vilius-laptop:~$ lsmod | grep rtl
btrtl                  36864  1 btusb
bluetooth            1015808  17 btrtl,btmtk,btintel,btbcm,bnep,btusb,rfcomm
rtl8821ae             368640  0
btcoexist             290816  1 rtl8821ae
rtl_pci                40960  1 rtl8821ae
rtlwifi               143360  3 rtl_pci,rtl8821ae,btcoexist
mac80211             1769472  3 rtl_pci,rtl8821ae,rtlwifi
cfg80211             1372160  2 rtlwifi,mac80211

None of missing modules are blacklisted in /etc/modprobe.d/. After loading them and restarting bluetooth service BT device is not there:
vilius@vilius-laptop:~$ lsusb 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0424:2134 Microchip Technology, Inc. (formerly SMSC) Hub
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 03f0:521d HP, Inc HP hs3110 HSPA+ Mobile Broadband Device
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 05c8:0369 Cheng Uei Precision Industry Co., Ltd (Foxlink) HP HD Webcam
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0424:5534 Microchip Technology, Inc. (formerly SMSC) Hub

Firmware is available and wireless network works fine
vilius@vilius-laptop:~$ ls /lib/firmware/rtlwifi/rtl8821*
/lib/firmware/rtlwifi/rtl8821aefw_29.bin.zst  /lib/firmware/rtlwifi/rtl8821aefw.bin.zst  /lib/firmware/rtlwifi/rtl8821aefw_wowlan.bin.zst

Maybe someone can point out where to dig?
Ubuntu 24.10, x86_64, 6.11.0-9-generic

It turned out that the disk encryption was not related.
The issue was solved by disabling the Fast Boot option in the BIOS
